# Play/stop media from locked screen

Tags: 20.04, lock-screen, shortcuts, spotify, media

I set keyboard shortcut to play/pause music (Keyboard Shortcuts -> Sound and Media -> Play (or play/pause)). I was able to use this shortcut also when screen was locked on Ubuntu 18.04. I have upgraded recently to 20.20 and the shortcut stopped working from locked screen. Is there anything I can do to make it work or any other way how to play/stop music from locked screen?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a workaround (I bound `ctrl + backslash` to play/pause media): in lock screen I have to hit `backslash` twice to make it work. However I am not sure if it is a bug or feature.